# How to select a SharePoint people picker using JQuery

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery

Im trying to select a sharepoint peoplepicker element in my form list.

i tried:

`$("#ctl00_ctl41_g_326d802c_cd66_443c_9312_18e0ff9786b9_ctl00_iwPermIterator_ctl19_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_UserField_upLevelDiv")`

But i had issues previously where the id would change, so that would not be a solution.

I also tried,

```
$("div[title='People Picker']")
```

But it would select 3 people pickers in my form list

Therefore, can someone suggest a way to select this element.

Edit: Here are 2 screenshots of the people-picker i have in my SharePoint environment.

I would like to update the reason for this behaviour is we are using a  custom form (infowise forms which made all peoplepickers have the same title.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: @harshalgite hi we are using sharepoint 2016

Comment: what exactly do you want to read from the people picker?

Comment: @harshal gite i have a drop-down, and the selected item should be appended to the peoplesPicker element.

Comment: Normally i would something such as 

 $("div[title='People Picker']").append(SelectedDropDownItem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed earlier, please modify the code snippet with index to choose the people picker needed:

```
$("div[title='People Picker']")[0]
```

Comment: Hi, we are using Sharepoint 2016, for my case all 3 people picker's title is People Picker for some reason..

Comment: Above is testing in SharePoint 2013 in my side, I will test in SharePoint 2016 again and give you update later.

Comment: I tested in SharePoint 2016, just the same as 2013, the each people picker title will be the samne as each field name in the list form, Can you please try to create a new list for a test ?

Comment: I will update the capture with SharePoint 2016 environment.

Comment: thanks, we are using Sharepoint 2016 on premise if that helps, i'll get back to you when i reach my office.

Comment: Of course, will wait for your updates.

Comment: Hello, i created a new list with a people-pickers Field, And surprisingly the Title was the name of the column.  In this case, how can i resolve this issue in my main list?

Comment: So this issue should be existed in the specific list, you can check if there are some Javascript code which will change the div title property in your side in the page, I assume this should be caused by custom JavaScript code.

Comment: Are you using InfoPath form instead of default form ?

Comment: yes we are using custom forms,( infowise )

Comment: Yes, if you are using InfoPath form, all people picker will have same title "People Picker" in Dom. A workaround is to use index to filter the people picker you want to get like $("div[title='People Picker']")[0]

Comment: We will be meeting some clients, i will inform you tomorrow how it goes, Thanks.

Comment: hi, i would like to update this post, your solution has worked with me  can i mark it as answer?

Comment: Yes Jilo, wait a minute, I will update my reply and then you could Mark it as answer.

Comment: Done, please refresh and check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the functions provided by SharePoint itself. The following line gives you the id of the top level element of your people picker (replace "YourFieldInternalName" by internal name which you have given).

```
var pickerDivID = WPQ2FormCtx.ListSchema.YourFieldInternalName.TopLevelElementId
```

If this does not work, `WPQ2FormCtx` might not be the correct object. Just open browser console and type *WPQ or FormCtx*, you will get some like *WPQ2FormCtx or WPQ4FormCtx*. Use that in the above statement.

You can use this ID wherever you want. To get values from peoplepicker as shown below.

```
var pickerObject = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[pickerDivID];
```

This object contains all the information in the people picker column of the form.

Open the form in new page or by going to top ribbon -> list -> default new form. Try getting that wpformctx here. And use that one in the code.

Ideally it should work with infowise customization as well because SharePoint fields remain the same.

Comment: hi @harshal gite i tried all 3 (WPQ2FormCtx, FormCtx, WPQ ) in google chrome console, they all return
 VM5612:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: WPQ is not defined

Do i need some sort of library to use them?

Comment: type WPQ or formctx and do not hit enter. you will be get the correct one in intellisense. No you do not need any library

Comment: i typed in WPQ, only varPartWPQ2 exists as an object, The rest are are not defined. i also typed formctx but did not get anything recommended by the intellisense.

Comment: Are you trying with your form open in modal dialogue?

Comment: @ harshal gite, Actually we are using infowise forms. And we are opening the forms as Tabs with the help of infowise.